# Error implementing posix message queue - "Function not implemented"

Tags: c++, linux, posix, message-queue, ubuntu-10.10

I have written this code to make a posix message queue. But I am receiving an error "Function not implemented".

Q1. Is it a platform related issue ? [Am using Ubuntu 10.10] I read somewhere that I need to rebuild my kernel to enable message queues !?

Q2. I also read something about starting the mqueue server before actually using message queues ?

Can someone please explain..

```
#include <mqueue.h>     /* message queue stuff */
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>     /* for getopt() */
#include <errno.h>      /* errno and perror */
#include <fcntl.h>      /* O_flags */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

mqd_t msgQueueDescriptor;
mq_attr attr;

char Msg[]="msg";

attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;
attr.mq_msgsize = sizeof(Msg);
attr.mq_flags = 0;

msgQueueDescriptor = mq_open("/myQueue", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IROTH | S_IWOTH , attr );
cout << msgQueueDescriptor << " " << errno << " " << strerror(errno);
mq_close(msgQueueDescriptor);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: According to `mq_overview(7)`, POSIX messages queues are enabled by default when building the kernel, but the Ubuntu packagers might have turned them off.

Comment: @larsmans How can I confirm that? Will that be a part of release notes of Ubuntu? And how can I turn it back on in case its really turned off?

Comment: I would find ubuntu really weird if they really turned them off. On fedora 15, your example compiles and links successfully.

Comment: You might want to download a kernel source package via Synaptic and check its configuration; the error you got is surely `ENOSYS`, meaning no system call. Turning MQs on would involve recompiling the kernel, I think. I'd be very surprised if MQs are not supported in the default kernel, though.

Comment: This compiles, links and runs on Ubuntu 10.04.3. To verify your kernel is configured with the needed flag. look at `/boot/config*`.

Comment: @n.m. `CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE=y` `CONFIG_POSIX_MQUEUE_SYSCTL=y` is what I can see in this file related to mqueues. But it seems they are enabled?

Comment: I'm sure you just made a mistake in your code in your question, but in the call to `mq_open` you should give the attribute argument as a pointer (i.e. `&attr` in your code snippet).

Comment: @VJovic well yes, some distros just are weird like that.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Good point. The compiler will not catch it, because the function is prototyped with `...` in place of the fourth parameter.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for pointing that out, although I was having the same problem when I used `NULL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have realized what the problem was, or rather a mistake from side.

This is what I read from [here](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.2/neutrino/lib_ref/m/mq_open.html) -

> [ In reference to mq_open( ) ]
>
> Returns: A valid message queue descriptor if the queue is successfully
> created, or -1 (errno is set).

So, I should be checking the value for errno *only* when an error actually occurs!. But in the above code I am just printing the value irrespective of an error occured or not, and thus it is printing the error message corresponding to some *garbage* value stored in errno.

So my code should be something like this -

```
if ((msgQueueDescriptor = mq_open("/myQueue", O_RDWR|O_CREAT, 0664 ,NULL ) == -1))
{
    cout << msgQueueDescriptor << " " << errno << " " << strerror(errno);
}
else
{
   cout << "All is well" ;
}
```

*Did I just made a fool outa myself :p*

PS: As far as message queues being enabled on Ubuntu 10.10 is concerned, I checked the flags as mentioned by "n.m.", they are very much enabled, and I am able to use the message queues now. Thanks all of you - larsmans, VJovic, n.m.,  Joachim Pileborg,  jørgensen.

About my second question

> Q2. I also read something about starting the mqueue server before
> actually using message queues ?

I think that is a requirement specifically on QNX.

Comment: It is important to remember that no library function sets `errno` to zero (at least, not in the standard C library), and that you should only inspect `errno` if the last function that might set it actually indicated that it failed.  Counter-example: on Solaris, many of the stdio calls check whether the output is a tty, and leave `errno == ENOTTY` when it isn't, even though the call succeeded perfectly.  So, yes, you made a small fool of yourself, but you learned from it, so it is a valuable experience.

Comment: As for Q2: if there's nothing in the manual pages about starting `mqueue server` (and I've never seen any mention of it), then there's no need to do so - regardless of what QNX thinks about the situation.

Comment: Checking `errno` should only be done if a function fails (unless specified otherwise). Actually, reading the official POSIX specification on `errno` [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/errno.html), it says _No function in this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 shall set errno to 0. The setting of errno after a successful call to a function is unspecified unless the description of that function specifies that errno shall not be modified._

Comment: Verdict: Not a fool. Helpful learner, yes :) Cheers